# how to set date field not to display past date

Tags: entities, datetime

In a content I need a date field for which I have used Date module. Widget type used for this is popup calender. But when the calender popup appears I want to display only today's date and future dates, I don't want to display any of the previous date, not even a single day.

How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Field validation](https://drupal.org/project/field_validation) module to create validation for the date field.

You can follow below step to achieve this.

- Go to  Administration -> Structure -> Content types and it will
  display the list of content type.
- Click on 'Manage Fields' links for your content type and it will display the list of fields for your content type.
- Edit your 'Date field' from the list of fields.
- Select '0 years from now' from the drop down 'Starting year' under 'More settings and values'. It will not display the previous year date in the popup.
- You can set the default values for the date field under 'default values' section.
- Save the settings.
- Edit again your fields.
- Click on 'Validation' tab in top of page.
- Click on 'Date range2' link in the page.
- Select 'value' from the drop down 'column'
- Select 'Cycle of date' as global and set '-0 day' for the 'Minimum
  date' textfield. Now, it will generate the error if date is less than today's date.